# Strange Issue with HttpWebRequest (Pattern of Failed and Successful Responses)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, httpwebrequest

I am connecting to an API to get the orderbook of a ticker on a cryptocurrency exchange. When I do this with all other exchanges, I get no issues. When doing it for this exchange, I am rejected (error response) about half of the time, and it seems as though I am rejected after two or three requests in a row. I know that it is not a rate limiting issue because I am capable of typing the URL into my browser instead of HttpWebRequest and refreshing a ridiculous amount of times without getting errors (and getting updated data). I am thus led to believe that there is a problem with either how I am going about using HttpWebRequest or with it itself. What could be causing this strange issue?

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    string responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    return responseString;
                }
            }
```

Obviously, I would expect to not get any errors, as typing the very same URL into google, outside of HttpWebRequest, does not give me any issues at all. The URL is https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/book/BTCEUR. In case any of you want to try writing the same code and seeing how often errors occur, use the above URL. You could replace BTCEUR with other tickers on the exchange, but the result is the same (as far as errors go).

I can't even check the response code, because attempting to get a response code gets me an error. The error is a website page that says "Not found", which is bull, because it could have found that exact page just seconds before.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Check the status of the http response.  A good response should return a 200 Done.  Anything else is an error.  For crypto code to work the number of bytes encrypted must equal the number of bytes uses to decrypt.  So normally to find the error I compare the bytes sent count to bytes receive count.  The debug code to find where the bytes were lost.  In this case it is probably in the http message.

Comment: I can't even check the response code, because attempting to get a response code gets me an error. The error is a website page that says "Not found", which is bull, because it could have found that exact page just seconds before.